# Optimized the color render function

Tags: javascript, function, svg, optimization

I have a big data to handle.
They need to be classified into 4 colors, and render to the SVG.

My function is:(parameter A B C are used to do something....)

```
function mapRender(dataArray,A,B,color1,color2,color3,color4,C){

  //......do somthing.......

  var colorPlusAry = $.grep(dataArray, function(item,key){
      var vote_percentage = parseInt(item.vote_percentage);
      var result = vote_percentage>=0 && vote_percentage <50;
      return result;
   });

  //......do somthing.......
}
```

I use grep to generate the new array which the item has same color, and render to SVG.

```
function colorDistrict(colorArray,color){
         var village = '';
         var fillColor = 'fill:'+color;
         for(var item in colorArray) {
             village = colorArray[item].village;
             $('svg').find('path').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                if(village) {
                   if(id.substring(6) === village){
                      $(this).attr('style',fillColor);
                   }
                }
            });
         }
}
colorDistrict(colorPlusAry,color1);  //Render 4 array
```

It works successfully, but the data is too large and make render slowly, when I trigger the function, it takes several seconds to react...
How can I optimize this function to render the color?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but maybe some kind of observable pattern for the colouring would be more efficient **after** the first render..

Comment: what's the structure of the objects in `dataArray` and in `colorArray`? and how do you call `colorDistrict`?

Comment: How often do you update the map colours?  What causes it to re-render?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau when user click it will re-render, actually it's different data render in same SVG map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimization is a difficult business without the real data, and without knowing the precise DOM structure. I can only give some hints from what I see:

The costly process is interacting with the DOM. Looking at the `colorDistrict()` function, the two loops seem to be independent. It would then make sense to run the  `.each()` loop only once, and the loop over the `colorArray` as the nested one. The latter only contains precomputed values and should run much faster.

Looking at what these loops really do, you can write them much more semantic. You compare the collection of all paths and the `colorArray` for intersection, and then assign a style to a filtered list of paths.

```
function colorDistrict (colorArray, color){
     var fillColor = 'fill:' + color;

     // filter the paths to find those mentioned in colorArray
     var relevantPaths = $('svg').find('path').filter(function () {
         var village = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);

         // boolean to indicate the village is part of the colorArray
         var included = colorArray.some(function (item) {
             return item.village === village;
         });

         return included;
    });

    relevantPaths.attr('style', fillColor);
}
```

If I understand correctly what you are doing, the `colorDistrict()` function is executed multiple times, once for every color you assign. Do the `<path>` elements change between rendering the different colors? If not, you should execute `$('svg').find('path')` only once and cache the found paths for reuse inside that function.

```
var paths = $('svg').find('path');

function colorDistrict (colorArray, color){
     var fillColor = 'fill:' + color;

     var relevantPaths = paths.filter(function () {
         ...
     });
}
```